# AngularJS UI carousel custom previous and next button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is it possible to make custom previous and next button AngularJS UI carousel? I also want to have two elements of step. For me, documentation is not very clear.

I would be very great full if someone gave me an example or direction on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the markup easily.  Here is the [template for the carousel from Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/carousel/carousel.html)

```
<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides().length > 1">
        <li ng-repeat="slide in slides()" ng-class="{active: isActive(slide)}" ng-click="select(slide)"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
    <a ng-click="prev()" class="carousel-control left" ng-show="slides().length > 1">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a ng-click="next()" class="carousel-control right" ng-show="slides().length > 1">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

You can, of course, override the CSS for `.carousel-control.left` and `.carousel-control.right`.  If you need a complete element replacement, you can do some DOM manipulation.

You can also try to play games with the `$templateCache` and override the template completely.  The resource name in the `$templateCache` is "'template/carousel/carousel.html'"

Here is an example of doing that:

```
app.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/carousel/carousel.html", "<div>REPLACED!!!</div>")
});
```

So, you could modify the template to be something slightly different.

**WARNING** This is implementation specific.  If they change the implementation later, this approach may break.  Prefer CSS manipulation over template replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I Just overrided the default styles of the carrousel

```
    .glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        content: "\f054";
    }
    .glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        content: "\f053";
    }
```